# Not Null Constraint Fail

Tags: python, django, django-models

I looked at a ton of these issues on stack overflow, but none of the solutions seemed to help me. I've tried Null=True and Blank=True as well as default=None and they all give errors. Anyone have any ideas? Thanks so much!

The error I'm getting is this:

> NOT NULL constraint failed: first_app_trip.messages_id

My models:

```
class Trip(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    destination = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    description = models.TextField()
    start_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False)
    end_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="created_trips")
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="joined_trips", default=None)
    messages = models.ForeignKey(Message, related_name="messages", default=None )
    notes = models.ForeignKey(Note, related_name="notes", default=None)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)

class Message(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="author")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)

class Note(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="notes")
```

My Views:

```
def create(request):
    user = current_user(request)
    print user.id
    return render(request, 'first_app/create_trip.html')

def add(request):
    user = current_user(request)
    print user

    trip = Trip.objects.create(
        title = request.POST.get('title'),
        destination = request.POST.get('destination'),
        description = request.POST.get('description'),
        start_date = request.POST.get('start_date'),
        end_date = request.POST.get('end_date'),
        creator = user
        )
    print trip
    return redirect('/user_profile')
```

Comment: after you added new option to the model description you need to do create and apply migration, do you?

Comment: Update errors also, where error is coming.

Comment: Hi @BearBrown I did migrate

Comment: The error is NOT NULL constraint failed: first_app_trip.messages_id and it's in the django debug and in my terminal console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python **case sensitive**

try it

```
class Trip(models.Model):

    messages = models.ForeignKey(Message, related_name="messages", null=True, blank=True )
    # in this line     case sensitive                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

next:

```
./manage.py makemigrations first_app
./manage.py migrate first_app
```

after it try your action

Comment: it happens, glad to help)

Comment: it kinda worked for me this answer although i'm getting the relation as blank